# Ruby case statement on a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, branch, case-statement

This is going to sound weird, but I would love to do something like this:

```
case cool_hash
  when cool_hash[:target] == "bullseye" then do_something_awesome
  when cool_hash[:target] == "2 pointer" then do_something_less_awesome
  when cool_hash[:crazy_option] == true then unleash_the_crazy_stuff
  else raise "Hell"
end
```

Ideally, I wouldn't even need to reference the has again since it's what the case statement is about.  If I only wanted to use one option then I would "case cool_hash[:that_option]", but I'd like to use any number of options.  Also, I know case statements in Ruby only evaluate the first true conditional block, is there a way to override this to evaluate every block that's true unless there is a break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in **ruby 3.0** you can do the following with [pattern matching](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html)

```rb
# assuming you have these methods, ruby 3 syntax
def do_something_awesome = "something awesome "
def do_something_less_awesome = "something LESS awesome"
def unleash_the_crazy_stuff = "UNLEASH the crazy stuff "
```

you can do

```rb
def do_the_thing(cool_hash)
  case cool_hash
  in target: "bullseye" then do_something_awesome
  in target: "2 pointer" then do_something_less_awesome
  in crazy_option: true then unleash_the_crazy_stuff
  else raise "Hell"
  end
end
```

will return

```rb
do_the_thing(target: "bullseye")
=> "something awesome "

do_the_thing(target: "2 pointer")
=> "something LESS awesome"

do_the_thing(crazy_option: true)
=> "UNLEASH the crazy stuff "
```

in **ruby 2.7** it still works

```rb
# need to define the methods differently
def do_something_awesome; "something awesome "; end
def do_something_less_awesome; "something LESS awesome"; end
def unleash_the_crazy_stuff; "UNLEASH the crazy stuff "; end

# and when calling the code above to do the switch statement
# you will get the following warning
warning: Pattern matching is experimental, and the behavior may change
         in future versions of Ruby!
```

Answer (score 22):

You could also use a lambda:

```
case cool_hash
when -> (h) { h[:key] == 'something' }
  puts 'something'
else
  puts 'something else'
end
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

Your code is very close to being valid ruby code.  Just remove the variable name on the first line, changing it to be:

```
case
```

However, there is no way to override the case statement to evaluate multiple blocks.  I think what you want is to use `if` statements.  Instead of a `break`, you use `return` to jump out of the method.

```
def do_stuff(cool_hash)
  did_stuff = false

  if cool_hash[:target] == "bullseye"
    do_something_awesome
    did_stuff = true
  end

  if cool_hash[:target] == "2 pointer"
    do_something_less_awesome
    return  # for example
  end

  if cool_hash[:crazy_option] == true
    unleash_the_crazy_stuff
    did_stuff = true
  end

  raise "hell" unless did_stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response! Greatly appreciated. This helps and hopefully over time I will think in Ruby.

Answer (score 5):

I think, following is the better way to do the stuff you want.

```
def do_awesome_stuff(cool_hash)
  case cool_hash[:target]
    when "bullseye"
      do_something_awesome
    when "2 pointer"
      do_something_less_awesome
    else
     if cool_hash[:crazy_option]
      unleash_the_crazy_stuff
     else
      raise "Hell"
     end
  end
end
```

Even in case's else part you can use 'case cool_hash[:crazy_option]' instead of 'if' if there are  more conditions. I prefer you to use 'if' in this case because there is only one condition.